# Как изменить форму объекта с квадрата на прямоугольник?

Tags: c#, wpf

уже много что пробовал, чтобы изменить объект на нужную форму, но PriceSelectionValue не хочет принимать два значения. Можно ли как-то исправить код?

```
            {
                var values = _priceSelectionSeries[barIndex];

                PriceSelectionValue zone = new PriceSelectionValue(_buff[i]);
                zone.MaximumPrice = _buff[i];
                zone.MinimumPrice = _buff[i];
                zone.HeightFactor = 100; 
                zone.ObjectColor = _verticalClusterColor;
                zone.PriceSelectionColor = _verticalClusterColor;
                zone.VisualObject = ObjectType.OnlyCluster;

                if (i == _middle)
                {
                    zone.Size = 50;
                    zone.VisualObject = _verticalVisualObject;
                    zone.ObjectColor = _verticalObjectColor;
                }

                values.Add(zone);
            }
```

Comment: В строке "zone.Size = 50" задаётся размер визуального объекта, в данном случае квадрат со стороной 50px, как можно сделать из него прямоугольник? К примеру, размером 50х20

Comment: У вас Winforms или WPF? Какая библиотека для рисования?

Comment: Я использую  WPF

Comment: `PriceSelectionValue` - что за класс?

Comment: `HeightFactor` - название говорит само за себя, не?